# Trying to import a python snippet to C/C++ (PI spigot algorithm)

Tags: python, c, algorithm, pi

Some time ago (I can't remember where) I find this python snippet which implents a spigot algorithm for calculating digits of Pi:

```
def pi_digits():
    """generator for digits of pi"""
    q,r,t,k,n,l = 1,0,1,1,3,3
    while True:
        if 4*q+r-t < n*t:
            yield n
            q,r,t,k,n,l = (10*q,10*(r-n*t),t,k,(10*(3*q+r))/t-10*n,l)
        else:
            q,r,t,k,n,l = (q*k,(2*q+r)*l,t*l,k+1,(q*(7*k+2)+r*l)/(t*l),l+2)

digits = pi_digits()
for i in range(30): print digits.next()
```

Now I wanna implent this in C++. My try was:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

typedef long long ll;

void help() {
  std::cout << "Usage: pi2 <digits>" << std::endl;
  exit(1);
}

void pi(const long long digits) {
  ll q, r, t, k, n, l;
  q=1;
  r=0;
  t=1;
  k=1;
  n=3;
  l=3;
  for(ll i=0; i<digits; ++i) {
    if(4*q+r-t < n*t) {
      std::cout << n;
      q=10*q;
      r=10*(r-n*t);
      n = ( 10 * ( 3 * q + r) / t ) - 10 * n; //Thanks to maverik
    } else {
      q=q*k;
      r=(2*q+r)*l;
      t=t*l;
      k=k+1;
      n=(q*(7*k+2)+r*l)/(t*l);
      l=l+2;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if(argc<2) help();
  ll digits = 0;
  if(digits=atoll(argv[1])<1) help();
  pi(digits);
  return 0;
}
```

But it never calls std::cout::operator<<, while the python version works.
Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you post incomplete code? Should we add the rest manually in order having a compilable .c file?

Comment: i'll post the complete file.

Comment: Shall I take that as a compliment? ;D

Comment: @user1923694, sure, no offence mentioned :)

Comment: This algorithm is awesome! You can get a million digits of PI in like 5 minutes!

Comment: @Vreality 5 minutes is not that good. Using GMP and Gauss-Legendre you can calculate 1M digits in less than 3 seconds.

Comment: @user1923694 Wow. Well, pi certainly is impressive. Thank you for sharing a better algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is your code not performing the equivalent calculations in the two languages.

There are(as far as I see) two reasons for this:

1. In this python code, all the calculations are done at the same time:

   ```
   q,r,t,k,n,l = (q*k,(2*q+r)*l,t*l,k+1,(q*(7*k+2)+r*l)/(t*l),l+2)
   ```

   In the C code, the calculations are performed one at a time, so every one uses the result of the previous ones instead of using the old values(like the python code does).
2. You're using `int`s in python, and `long long`s in C.
   The division in C code will produce `long long`s, while those in python(assuming python 2), will produce rounded-down `int`s.

   This could also create miscalculations which can cause your condition to never be true.

P.S.
Implementing this in C from scratch is probably a better idea than porting a python algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there should be (according to the python code):

```
n = ( 10 * ( 3 * q + r) / t ) - 10 * n;
```

And there:

```
if ( 4 * q + r - t < n * t) ...
```

Or I've missed something?

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake there.
But that doesn't fix the problem at all.

Comment: P.S I don't see `drop()` called somewhere in your updated code

Comment: Well, that's from an older revision of the example.